# How to enable a bit in octed only if it's 0?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit

For example, I have the following number:

```
0x FF 00 FF
```

Now, I want the 00 part to be 1 only if it's 0. Do I need to check each byte or is there a bit-trick which can be used here?

**Example:**

I have an unsigned long IP, and I hash it with a string function, but the function terminates on null bytes, so I need to set all null bytes to 1:

0x7F000001 (127.0.0.1, can be 0x0100007F but depends on platform anyway)

now, I want to make the 0 bytes into ones:

0x7F010101 (so it will become 127.1.1.1)

Is the only way of doing what I want, this

```
char ip_sz[5];

*(unsigned long*)ip_sz = ulong_ip;

if (!ip_sz[0]) ip_sz[0] = 1;
if (!ip_sz[1]) ip_sz[1] = 1;
if (!ip_sz[2]) ip_sz[2] = 1;
if (!ip_sz[3]) ip_sz[3] = 1;
```

?

Really, curiosity. I don't care about performance because I know the compiler will optimize this anyway.

Comment: Can you explain with example what exactly you need?

Comment: What's the data type for this? Are we talking about bits 8-15 in an integral type?

Comment: OR it with `11`? If it's 1, it'll stay 1.

Comment: Hint: what is the binary representation of 0x ?? 00 ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check the entire byte to be zero by applying a *bit mask* (i.e. a number containing ones in positions that you wish to check and zeros in all other positions<sup>*</sup>) to it.

In your case, you need a bit mask with eight consecutive ones in zero-based positions 7 through 15, inclusive, i.e. `0x00FF00`. If you apply bitwise "AND" `&` to the mask and to a number `n`, the result would be zero only when all bits of `n` in positions 7 through 15 are zeros. Otherwise, the result would be some non-zero number.

```
int n = 0xFF00FF;
int mask = 0x00FF00;
if ((n & mask) == 0) {
    ... // Modify n as needed
}
```

You can construct an eight-bit bit mask manually, or use left shift operator, like this:

```
(0xFF)       // 0x000000FF
(0xFF << 8)  // 0x0000FF00
(0xFF << 16) // 0x00FF0000
(0xFF << 24) // 0xFF000000
```

> so, I would still have to do four `if`'s?

In this specific case `if`s are not necessary, because of a little trick in C: you can use `!` to convert zero to one and any other number to zero. I will illustrate this with a single byte; you can use bit shifts to expand this to integers.

```
uint8_t n = ... // Some value
n = n | (!n);   // Here is the trick
```

The last operation converts 0x00 to 0x01, while all other values (i.e. 0x01 through 0xFF, inclusive) remain intact ([demo](http://ideone.com/Opw8ol)).

<sup>*</sup> The construction of a bit mask depends on the operation that you apply to it. For "AND" and "XOR" you mark the desired bits with ones, while for "OR" you mark them with zeros.

Comment: so, I wil still have to do four `if`'s

Comment: I looked at it, the `flip` function with my clang compiles to a "testb ; sete ; orb" sequence of intel instructions. The thing is, one still needs to separate the four octets, do this with each one of them, and construct the resulting 32 bit value.

Comment: @BuellaGábor That's precisely why I added this to my answer: "I will illustrate this with a single byte; you can use bit shifts to expand this to integers."

Comment: BTW, I tried the naive approach as well, with four `if`s, clang generated ASM without branches, with some clever conditional moves.

Answer (score 1):

I googled "detect zero byte in word". I advice you do the same.
This one is branch-less, uses five operations ( at least in C, the number machine code instructions depend on your compiler, and platform, and what-not).
I guess you don't win a lot with this, but for fun, here it is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

static void print(uint32_t x)
{
  printf("0x%08" PRIX32 "\n", x);
}

int main()
{
  uint32_t x;

  x = 0xb300ff00; /* <- an example, should work with any 32 bit value */
  print(x);
  print(x - 0x01010101);
  print((x - 0x01010101) & ~x);
  print((x - 0x01010101) & ~x & 0x80808080);
  print(((x - 0x01010101) & ~x & 0x80808080) >> 7);
  print(x | ((x - 0x01010101) & ~x & 0x80808080) >> 7); /* <- the final result */

  return 0;
}
```

EDIT:

As side note, this is generated by a compiler:

```
leal  -16843009(%rdi), %eax 
movl  %edi, %ecx
notl  %ecx
andl  %ecx, %eax
shrl  $7, %eax
andl  $16843009, %eax
orl %edi, %eax
```

Another side note: this of course can work with 64 bit integers the same way, working on eight bytes in parallel, using the same few instructions.